# Is there any way to send some text through Ethereum transaction

Tags: validation, blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to send 0 ETH transaction which will be able to send some readable text. I was trying it through data, but it is only used for smart contracts. Can you help me find some solution?

Comment: Showing some code would increase your chances of getting a response.

Comment: Can you explain please what your ultimate goal is here? There may be alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Data field can be used for non-smart contract transactions as well.

You are free to put any text to Data field.

However there are very few use cases where you would want to do so. It is better to pass around messages signed with the private key corresponding the address.